# Service to Service secure communication among services run behind spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I have couple of microservices running behind the Spring cloud gateway and all microservices run behind are protected by OAuth2 protocol using spring authorization server. Everything is working fine but few of the microservices would like to exchange data with each other but these resource servers are protected.

I have created the registered client (for each microservice with their own client id & client secret) at authorization server and as well as respective OAuth2 client configuration at each service. I have configured this setup with Webclient to fetch data from other services needed as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("server");

        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();
        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

....
....
application.yml (similar config. for resource-client2)
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          server:
            scope: ROLE_RESOURCE_CLIENT1
            client-id: resource-client1
            client-secret: '{noop}secret1'
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-name: resource-client1-client-credentials
        provider:
          server:
            token-uri: http://localhost:9001/oauth2/token

      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:9001
```

and at authorization server, the client configuration is as follows

```
private final static RegisteredClient resource1ServiceClient = RegisteredClient.withId("2")
            .clientId("resource-client1")
            .clientSecret("{noop}secret1")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .build();

    private final static RegisteredClient resource2ServiceClient = RegisteredClient.withId("3")
            .clientId("resource-client2")
            .clientSecret("{noop}secret2")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .build();
```

when I'm trying to do rest call using webclient from resource client1 to resource client2, I'm getting NPE error because the spring authorization server is not providing the access token.
error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.getAccessToken()" because "tokenResponse" is null
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://localhost:8082/hello2 [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:71) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.authorize(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$authorizeClient$22(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:485) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
```

Not sure what went wrong with my setup or missing the logic to get it done. using latest spring version & spring authorization server version 1.0.0 . kindly help

Comment: Yay! I've been waiting for someone to try this setup. It looks like it should come fairly close to working to me. I can try and replicate your setup and see what happens.

Comment: I was able to do something very similar by slightly modifying the [messages-client sample](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/messages-client) from the repository. I even added another `RegisteredClient` to the authorization server, and use `client_credentials` to access the client/resource-server which then uses another `RegisteredClient` to access the other resource-server, and it worked successfully. The only thing I don't understand in your config is `scope: ROLE_RESOURCE_CLIENT1`. What happens when you remove it?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide your entire setup (all 3 applications) as a sample github repo so I could use exactly your setup. Is that possible?